# count occurrences of values in a column conditioned to values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with three columns: tasks, shift and worker_ID. A task in tasks can be performed by several workers in worker_ID.

```
tasks | shift | worker_ID
------|-------|----------
111   | 127   | 233
111   | 127   | 34
111   | 127   | 455
333   | 127   | 444
333   | 127   | 34
333   | 127   | 200
333   | 127   | 100
444   | 127   | 34
444   | 127   | 567
444   | 127   | 888
666   | 125   | 100
666   | 125   | 200
666   | 125   | 345
666   | 125   | 100
555   | 125   | 34
555   | 125   | 100
555   | 125   | 457
```

I would like to create an sql query to count the occurrences of each worker_ID in each specific shift to return the following additional column (num_occ):

```
tasks | shift | worker_ID | num_occ
------|-------|-----------|--------
111   | 127   | 233       |  0
111   | 127   | 34        |  0
111   | 127   | 455       |  0
333   | 127   | 444       |  0
333   | 127   | 34        |  1
333   | 127   | 200       |  0
333   | 127   | 100       |  0
444   | 127   | 34        |  2
444   | 127   | 567       |  0
444   | 127   | 888       |  0
666   | 125   | 100       |  0
666   | 125   | 200       |  0
666   | 125   | 345       |  0
666   | 125   | 100       |  1
555   | 125   | 34        |  0
555   | 125   | 100       |  2
555   | 125   | 457       |  0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this most easily using variables:

```
 select t.*,
         (@rn := if(@ws = concat_ws(':', worker_id, shift), @rn + 1,
                    if(@ws := concat_ws(':', worker_id, shift), 0, 0)
                   )
         )
  from t cross join
       (select @rn := -1, @ws := '') params
  order by worker_id, shift;
```

Comment: "Most easily" says the guy who wrote the book I had in college. I thought I knew SQL until I see answers like this...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help this was very useful and get me going again! thanks also to justiceorjustus for hinting about Gordon's books, I think I will have a look at few. Regards Luca

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I missed the fact that you were using mysql; this solution will not work in MySQL as MySQL does not support window functions; sorry about that.

I believe you can achieve the result you want using [the OVER clause and a windowed function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql).

```
SELECT tasks, [shift], worker_ID, 
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [shift], worker_ID ORDER BY tasks, [shift])) -1 AS num_occ
FROM Tasks
ORDER BY tasks;
```

I don't actually understand the output table that you showed in your example, but this code does achieve that same result.